# Add function to pre-existing struct

Tags: function, file, struct, rust

I want to add my own function to a pre-existing struct which I don't have control over. As concrete example I want to to create an instance of `std::fs::File`

```rust
let logfile = std::fs::OpenOptions::new().create(true).open("file.txt").unwrap();
```

Then I want somehow create my own function `fn foo()` so that I'm later able to do `logfile.foo();`

I'm not sure if this is even possible, to be honest.

Comment: Is there special information in your instance that `foo` relies on, or is all the information already in the `File` instance? If all the information is already in the `File` instance, then you can simply create a trait with a `foo` method then implement it for `File`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is exactly what traits can be used for. See "[Traits: Defining Shared Behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html)" in the Rust Book.

In short, you can define your own `trait Foo` and add e.g. a `fn foo(&self)` method to it, and then `impl Foo for std::fs::File`, which allows you to call `logfile.foo()`.

```rust
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self);
}

impl Foo for File {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("foo");
    }
}
```

---

Also your [`OpenOptions`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html) is missing either a call to [`write()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.write) or [`append()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.append). Otherwise, you'll receive an [`InvalidInput`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/enum.ErrorKind.html#variant.InvalidInput) error.

Here's a complete example:

```rust
use std::fs::{File, OpenOptions};

trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self);
}

impl Foo for File {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("foo");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let logfile = OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true) // or `.append(true)`
        .create(true)
        .open("file.txt")
        .unwrap();

    logfile.foo();
}
```